# Tema / template Wordpress para woocommerce com simulador

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Como devo pesquisar sobre um tema woocommerce que permita ao usuário do site montar o seu produto?

Preciso criar um site com um simulador como o desse site: http://makeacake.com.br

Alguém me recomenda um tema / template wordpress que permita esse simulador?

Answer (score 0):

O site em questão não utiliza wordpress creio. Mas caso queira pode usar algum plugin como Foodfy ou Foodpress para ajudar e fazer alguns edits css para dar a aparência que deseja.